# How to explode a dict and keep the relation with a certain column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

Given a dataframe:

```
id                      text
1   {'txt': 'en', 'longit': 0, 'latit': 0}
2   {'txt': 'fr', 'longit': 10, 'latit': 101, 'gross': 120.1}
```

I want to get this as output:

```
id     txt     longit    latit   gross
1       en       0         0      NaN
2       fr       10       101     120.1
```

What I did:

```
l=df.text.to_list()
c=pd.DataFrame(eval(str(l)))
```

The lines above works to create a dataframe but I am not get the right result as I want the `id` column together.

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution, using [`pandas.json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html):

```
df['id'].to_frame().join(pd.json_normalize(df['text']))
```

Output:

```
   id txt  longit  latit  gross
0   1  en       0      0    NaN
1   2  fr      10    101  120.1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) on `axis=1` to keep the column `id` :

```
out = pd.concat([df["id"], c], axis=1)
```

Another solution :

```
out = pd.concat((df["id"], pd.DataFrame(df["text"].tolist())), axis=1)
```

##### # Output :

```
print(out)
  id txt  longit  latit  gross
0  1  en       0      0    NaN
1  2  fr      10    101  120.1
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative using **pd.Series**:

```
df = df.join(df.pop('text').apply(pd.Series))
'''
   id txt  longit  latit  gross
0   1  en       0      0    NaN
1   2  fr      10    101  120.1
'''
```

Comment: I like your use of `pop` here, @Bushmaster! +1